# Get IP Address with Adobe Air 2

Tags: air, actionscript-3

I'm building an app in Adobe Air 2 with AS3 and need to get the users ip address. From what I understand this code should work but is tracing: "::1" not an ip. Thank you.

```
var netInterfaces = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();

var addresses = netInterfaces[0].addresses;

var userIp = addresses[0].address;

trace(userIp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote actually returns the ip adress of the first network Interface it finds.
This is in your case the so called loopback device which is used for local connections

with IP4 the ip adress would be 127.0.0.1

with IP6 the ip-adress is ::1

Comment: shoot, how can I accomplish this then?? (and am I the only when that IPv6 confuses the crap out of)

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve, if you want to know the address the air app uses to connect to your server, try to get it on the server side, if you want every adresse but the localhost ones check the netInterfaces.name property, if you want only ip4 adresses filter the adresses from the address-array by type.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the real IP and not your localhost, use this:

```
private function getIp():String{
    var netInterfaces:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
    var addresses:Vector.<InterfaceAddress> = netInterfaces[1].addresses;
    return addresses[0].address;    
}
```

If you're on Android, don't forget to set permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: and don't forget to set permissions if your on Android:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var netInterfaces:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
if (netInterfaces && netInterfaces.length > 0) {    
  for each (var i:NetworkInterface in netInterfaces) {
    if (i.active) {
      var addresses:Vector.<InterfaceAddress> =i.addresses;
      for each (var j:InterfaceAddress in addresses) {
        trace("- Host : " + j.address);           
      }
    }
  }
}
```